# How to set pointer value in go?

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func doStuff(q interface{}) {
    *q = MyStruct{2}
}

type MyStruct struct {
    f1 int
}

func main() {
    ms := MyStruct{1}
    doStuff(&ms)
    fmt.Printf("Hello, playground: %v\n", ms)
}
```

Is it possible to set ms through pointer q to have new value `MyStruct{2}`? I am getting this error `invalid indirect of q (type interface {})`

Comment: It's possible but you need to use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) or [reflection](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/). The type `interface{}` is not a pointer type, so you cannot use pointer indirection on it.

Comment: Your question seems to imply that you think of `interface{}` as "any type". This is wrong. `interface{}` is **not** "any type" it is the empty interface, literally `interface{}` and a distinct fixed type like uint16, chan bool, []string or io.Reader. It is worth redoing the Tour of Go once more to become familiar with Go's types system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't using the `interface{}` type, since it's not a literal type you can memory address like you're attempting. An interface type describes general behavior, not a specific value.

If you use the `MyStruct` type directly, you can get a pointer and do what you want.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func doStuff(q *MyStruct) {
    *q = MyStruct{2}
}

type MyStruct struct {
    f1 int
}

func main() {
    ms := MyStruct{1}
    doStuff(&ms)
    fmt.Printf("Hello, playground: %v\n", ms)
}
```

[Go playground linke](https://play.golang.org/p/rguFFguFDhX)

Answer (score 2):

`interface{}` is not a pointer type. So, you cannot change it's underlying value.
Instead, you can modify q value and return it from the `doStuff` function if you really need to do so.

example:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func doStuff(q interface{}) interface{} {
    q = &MyStruct{2}
    return q
}

type MyStruct struct {
    f1 int
}

func main() {
    var ms interface{} = MyStruct{1}
    ms = doStuff(&ms)
    fmt.Printf("Hello, playground: %v\n", ms)
}
```